# How to update nested ObservableCollection from source to target?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following VM

```
 public class ScalesViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private sp_GetScalesCalibrations_Result m_CurrentCalibration = null;
    public sp_GetScalesCalibrations_Result CurrentCalibration
    {
        get { return m_CurrentCalibration; }
        set
        {
            m_CurrentCalibration = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentCalibration");
        }
    }
}
```

in sp_GetScalesCalibrations_Result claas i have this proerty:
public sp_GetHysteresis_Result Hysteresis { get; set; }
which have theis property:
public ObservableCollection Tests { get; set; }

the tests property i'm binding to a datagrid like so:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentCalibration.Hysteresis.Tests}" CellEditEnding="Tests_Changed" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50">
                                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="משקל" Binding="{Binding Weight, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, TargetNullValue='', StringFormat=\{0:0.000000\}}"/>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="הוריה בעליה" Binding="{Binding IncreasingIndication, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, TargetNullValue='', StringFormat=\{0:0.000000\}}"/>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="סטייה בעלייה" Binding="{Binding IncreasingDeviation, StringFormat=\{0:0.000000\}}" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource columnStyle}"/>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="הוריה בירידה" Binding="{Binding DecreasingIndication, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, TargetNullValue='', StringFormat=\{0:0.000000\}}"/>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="סטייה בעלייה" Binding="{Binding DecreasingDeviation, StringFormat=\{0:0.000000\}}" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource columnStyle}"/>
                                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="סטייה מותרת" Binding="{Binding PermittedDeviation, StringFormat=\{0:0.000000\}}" IsReadOnly="True" ElementStyle="{StaticResource columnStyle}"/>
                                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                                        </DataGrid>
```

when i run the program, it shows me the data and it looks good, when i'm changing data from the ui, for example the Weight field, the data inside the code changes has well.
But ... when i'm changing field from the code example take the Weight field and the IncreasingIndication field and minus them it will give me the IncreasingDeviation and this i want to display in the ui, and it's not happening

I've tried ti implement  INotifyPropertyChanged to sp_GetHysteresis_Result and sp_GetScalesCalibrations_Result like so:

```
public partial class sp_GetScalesCalibrations_Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private sp_GetHysteresis_Result m_Hysteresis;
    public sp_GetHysteresis_Result Hysteresis
    {
        get { return m_Hysteresis; }
        set
        {
            m_Hysteresis = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Hysteresis");
        }
    }

    #region "PropertyEvent Change"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion

}
public partial class sp_GetHysteresis_Result : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<sp_GetHysteresisTests_Result> m_Tests;
    public ObservableCollection<sp_GetHysteresisTests_Result> Tests
    {
        get { return m_Tests; }
        set
        {
            m_Tests = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentCalibration.Hysteresis.Tests");
        }
    }

    #region "PropertyEvent Change"
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

but still didn't work
I've tried  to force update target like so(hyst is the datagrid's name):

```
((DataGrid)hyst).GetBindingExpression(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty)
                  .UpdateTarget();
```

still didn't work

Comment: Does the 'sp_GetHysteresisTests_Result' class also implement 'INotifyPropertyChanged', and when 'weight' is changed, does it call 'NotifyPropertyChanged' ?

Comment: sp_GetHysteresisTests_Result does'nt implement 'INotifyPropertyChanged' nor weight call 'NotifyPropertyChanged when changing. but if i'm putting  ObservableCollection<sp_GetHysteresisTests_Result> Tests  inside the ScalesViewModel  it does work, but i need it inside

Comment: I would guess that it only worked because you added a whole item to the ObservableCollection, rather than changing an individual property. The simple rule is that anything you bind to needs to call `NotifyPropertyChanged`